# Functions and header files (ansi c)

Tags: c, macros, header

This is a question from job interview.Let's say we have "a.c" source file with some function and "a.h" as its header file.Also we have main.c file which calls that function.Now let's suppose we have "a.h" and "a.o"(object file) and a.c is unavailable.How do we call this function now?
(I had a hint that we need to use function pointers.Another hint is to do this using pre-compiler directives such as #define and #ifndef).
Also i would like to know how in .h file we know if we are linked properly to source file?
Thank You

Comment: This sounds like it was an intended to catch people who had only gotten half way trough "C for Dummies".

Answer (score 2):

Just include a.h from main.c and you can use the functions declared in a.h. Then just compile it with the same compiler version as a.o is build:

```
gcc -c main.c
gcc main.o a.o
```

Comment: I agree that this is the correct solution, but I have a feeling the person asked the question incorrectly. The hints don't have anything to do with the situation.

Comment: @mathepic: True, but the best thing I can do is answering the question. :)

Answer (score 2):

To compile main.c, you need the function definition. You already have that in a.h. So you would write:

```
// main.c
#include "a.h"

int main()
{
    foobar(); // Let's say this is the function from a.h
}
```

When compiling it, you would have to include the object file at the linking stage. So using gcc...

```
gcc -c main.c // Compile main.c to main.o
gcc -o main main.o a.o
```

No function pointers or macros needed.

Answer (score 2):

The way you describe it, you only need a header file to call the function. The header file contains the prototype of the function, which allows the compiler to know what the signature of the function is.

You would then link in your object file (which contains the compiled version of function) and everything would be OK.

I don't know why you would need functions pointers or pre-compiler directives. Maybe you didn't understand the question 100%?

Answer (score 0):

In main.c, call the function as normal.

Then compile main.c to main.o. `gcc -c main.c`

Then link a.o and main.o. `gcc main.o a.o`

Answer (score 0):

Something about this question sounds garbled.  How you write the function call in main depends solely on its *declaration* in a.h.  The presence or absence of a.c doesn't change that.  Certainly nothing involving macros or function pointers.

Compiling and linking are two distinct steps; the compiler checks that you're passing the right number and types of arguments and assigning the result to the right type of object based on the function's declaration, while the linker attempts to resolve the reference to the function's implementation in the machine code.

The result of compiling and linking is a binary sludge that may or may not have any obvious relationship to the original source code<sup>1</sup>.  Debug versions preserve varying levels of information to support source-level debuggers, but you can pretty much rely on release versions not preserving *any* useful source information.

---

1.  Every now and again someone asks for a tool to recover source code from an executable; this is often described as attempting to turn hamburger back into cows.